# Windows VPN is not saving login credentials

Tags: windows-10, vpn, credentials

Using Windows 10, I connect to my employers network via a VPN.  I am told by IT that I *should* be able to save login credentials, but it is not working for me.

In the VPN => Advanced Options dialog, I can edit and add my credentials and save, ensuring that the "Remember my sign-ing info" checkbox is ticked:

[image: Edit VPN Connection dialog]

And the credentials appear to be saved.

[image: VPN as saved]

However when I attempt to connect, the dialog is empty of values.

I have also gone to the properties dialog for the associated VPN Adapter, and ensured that "Remember my credentials" is checked.  I cannot use the "Automatically use my Windows logon name and password" option as this VPN does not allow CHAP Version 2.

Comment: I would have your IT Administrator help you set it up.

Comment: Oh, I would too.  The word from them is, "We don't know. It should be working."

Comment: I'm also having the same problem, so I suspect it is a Windows issue, not something specific to the VPN.